# SPA Dynamic Routing and Page Rendering

Tags: elm

I am new to `Elm`, probably have an incorrect understanding of the architecture and this may be an XY question (but I wouldn't know yet...)

Anyways, I am trying to create a url-routed SPA in Elm.  I am using `evancz/start-app` to generate individual dynamic pages using the [elm-achitecture-tutorial example 1](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/tree/master/examples/1) as a starting point for each 'page':

```
Frontend.Pages.Home.display : Signal Html
Frontend.Pages.Home.display = StartApp.start
    { model = 0
    , update = update
    , view = view
    }

type alias Model = Int

type Action = Increment | Decrement

update : Action -> Model -> Model
update action model =
  case action of
    Increment -> model + 1
    Decrement -> model - 1

view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick address Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [ countStyle ] [ text (toString model) ]
    , button [ onClick address Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    ]
```

I am using `TheSeamau5/elm-router` to

```
route : String -> Signal Html
route = Router.match
    [ "/" :-> Frontend.Pages.Home.display
    ] Frontend.Pages.Errors.FourOhFour.display
```

I am using `TheSeamau5/elm-history` to gather the latest url:

```
main : Signal Html.Html
main = Frontend.Routes.route History.path
```

Clearly this is the error;  I am passing a `Signal String` into a method that takes a `String`.  The problem is that if I use the following:

```
main = Signal.map Frontend.Routes.route History.path
```

which I would expect `Signal.map Frontend.Routes.route History.path` to be of type `Signal Html`, instead the compiler complains of a conflict:

```
The type annotation for `main` does not match its definition. 

7| main : Signal Html.Html
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ As I infer the type of values flowing through your program, I see a conflict between these two types:

Html.Html

Signal Html.Html
```

- What's going on here?  It seems like Signal.Map is "unpacking" the `Signal Html`.  Is this the case?

It seems my core question, at any rate, is:  **How can I present a single-page-app, routed to separate reactive 'pages' based on a `Signal String` while not reimplementing `Router`?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are ending up with a final result of `Signal (Signal Html)` and main is expecting `Signal Html`. I believe the error you are receiving is specifically for the type it is expecting for `Signal a`. It is saying, I was expecting `a` to be `Html` but in fact I found it to be `Signal Html`.

Here are the types we have:

```
Signal.map : (a -> result) -> Signal a -> Signal result
Frontend.Routes.route : String -> Signal Html
Historypath : Signal String
```

Then we have `Signal.map Frontend.Routes.route` which has the type `Signal String -> Signal (Signal Html)`.

We then apply `History.path` giving us the final result `Signal (Signal Html)`

If you change `route` to return `Html` rather than `Signal Html` you should be good to go.

Comment: Sorry I can't try what you're saying at the moment, but just so I understand, I would change the signature of Route to be `route : String -> Html`?  Won't that just forward the type error to the Route function?  The `Frontend.Pages.Home.display : Signal Html` can't change since I'm trying to expand on the framework tutorial (that looks like this: http://elm-lang.org/examples/buttons) except make it a SPA.  Wouldn't this involve removing the StartApp portion of the MVU?  Doesn't that destroy model-view-level interactivity except by changing the URL?

Comment: You are correct. Your `display` function would need to return just `Html`. If I am understanding correctly, `display` is implemented with `StartApp.start` which produces a `Signal.Html` which you're then returning. Is this correct?

Comment: Would you be willing to share your implementation of `display`? I would like to get a better idea of how we might defer wrapping it with `StartApp.start`.

Comment: Yeah, it's literally a function rename of `main` in https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/blob/master/examples/1/Main.elm and the related implementation is a copy-paste job from https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial/blob/master/examples/1/Counter.elm...  thus it's:

    Frontend.Pages.Home.display =
      StartApp.start
        { model = 0
        , update = update
        , view = view
        }

Comment: sorry about the formatting :)  (and thanks for your help!)

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible with the version of `StartApp` you are using. However, a new version of `StartApp` was published earlier today that I believe can help you achieve this. It accepts a `List (Signal action)` as input which is then passed to your view. I have not attempted this, but you should be able to pass in `History.path` as an action. I'll have to play with this more later and edit my answer. I think the answer I have here explains why you are getting the type error. You may wish to revise your question to be more clear.

Comment: Thanks again.  I revised the question;  Hopefully it is clearer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86811/discussion-between-zwerdlds-and-joe).